# Command line build android apk from Qt app results in cannot read from json file error

Tags: android, qt, ant

I need to build an android apk from my Qt app using command line. With android, jdk, ndk & ant set in the env, I am running the following Qmake command.

```
qmake project.pro -spec android-g++ CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler
make -j2
make install INSTALL_ROOT=android
/Users/buildmaster/Qt/5.7/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt --output android --verbose --input android-libMyProject.so-deployment-settings.json
```

Running the script ends up in the following error:
`Cannot read from input file: android-libMyProject.so-deployment-settings.json`

how can I get rid of above error & generate an android apk ?

Comment: Add full path to `deployment-settings.json` file. `androiddeployqt` can't find it.

Comment: excellent. thanks. That worked. I had to replace the INSTALL_ROOT=/fullpath/android as well to get the final apk built. So yes. it worked